# Is there a WebDriver implementation for Microsoft UI Automation (UIA)?

Tags: ui-automation, microsoft-ui-automation

I'm looking for a WebDriver implementation for [Microsoft UI Automation (UIA)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx) to automate desktop applications and store apps.

Just like what [Appium](http://appium.io) and [Appium for Mac](https://github.com/appium/appium-for-mac) have done, in addition to web applications and mobile apps, I think WebDriver API should be applicable to Windows desktop applications and store apps (formerly known as Metro apps) as well.

I'm going to implement a server that exposes WebDriver API and interacts with UI elements via UI Automation API internally. Do you know if there exist some open source projects doing this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of an existing project that wraps UIA with the WebDriver API.

But RAutomation might be a useful example to take a look at - it sounds a bit like what you describe, but with the Watir API as the design inspiration instead of WebDriver's API:

https://github.com/jarmo/RAutomation

Note that there's an experimental UIA driver included with RAutomation.

Also, in case it's useful, I have a github repo at the link below that contains a hello world program (ported across several languages) implemented using both the COM and .NET flavors of UIA:

https://github.com/billagee/test-polyglot/tree/master/printDesktopUiaElementName